# Bug in Spring cache? Why list.addAll make an effection on the result?

Tags: spring-mvc, arraylist, spring-cache

Hi I met an really strange bug. The method list.addAll do change the return result in Spring caches.

Let me be simple, the code is like this. Interface is this.

```
public interface CacheService {
    List<Integer> getIntegers(String key);
}
```

Then the implemetion.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = {"cache"},unless = "#result.isEmpty()")
public List<Integer> getIntegers(String key){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(Integer.valueOf(key));
    return list;
}
```

I test it in Rest Controller.

```
@Autowired
CacheService cacheService;
@RequestMapping("cache")
public List<Integer> cache(){
    List<Integer> listA= cacheService.getIntegers("11");
    listA.addAll(cacheService.getIntegers("22"));
    return listA;
}
```

I called the method then bug comes.
First call, I get

> [11,22]

This sure be the forever answer.
But next time, I get

> [11,22,22]

And then

> [11,22,22,22],[11,22,22,22,22]...

I'm pretty sure that the **listA.addAll(cacheService.getIntegers("22"));** is the cause. Once I change the code as below, everything work fine.

```
List<Integer> listA = cacheService.getIntegers("11");
List<Integer> listB = cacheService.getIntegers("22");
return Stream.of(listA,listB).flagMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can anyone give me an answer why and is it an bug? Or is it the wrong use of addAll?
I'm using spring-boot, dependencies is like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug in the cache abstraction *per se*. You are returning a mutable collection that is cached and you let the caller modify that collection. Most cache provider will serialize the data before storing it in the cache in such a way that the entry will not be modified. But you could configure your cache to use object references.

If you return a mutable object and you use object reference, any modification on the returned object will also affect that cache entry. I understand that's not what you want and there are a couple of ways you can workaround this:

- Be more clear in your contract and wrap your list in `Collections.unmodifiableList` - This is a breaking change but it makes it more obvious to the caller they have to copy your list if they want to modify it.
- Always serialize the content rather than storing an object reference. You haven't told us much about your setup but as far as I can see, you're using the default `CacheManager` (i.e. concurrent hash map in memory). That's going to store your object "as is" so you may want to use a different cache provider. Note that as of 4.3 you can also [configure that cache manager to serialize the content rather than storing a reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.java#L120-L135).

Comment: Thank you! I see that cacheManager always returns the same collection but not create a new one...

Comment: One more thing I'm using the default caffeine cache manager provided by spring boot. It seems that CaffeineCacheManager doesn't has a setStoreByValue method. However, thank you again!

Comment: That's not the default cache manager. If you're using  Caffeine, check the doc to enable serialization of entries.